# Kendo ASP.net MVC Grid Editor Popup Not Work

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, telerik-mvc

I have a stranger issue, The Kendo Grid for ASP.Net MVC work as expect except when I added any event for ant tool in the popup template, The popup window opens in the same page not poping up

Any Idea?

Answer (score 0):

I assume the event handler for the component in the popup is not found, thus a js error is thrown and the popup fails to initialize.

Move the event handlers to the page where the grid is or move them to a js file that is referenced in the grid's page.